# Usage of Encyption keys (CMEK) with CloudSQL databases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using CMEK key with CloudSQL for persistence. The CMEK was specified during the CloudSQL DB instance creation and understand it's used when storing data (update/inserts).
However, I want to understand how it's used during data retrieval.
Want to understand if it's used when data is retrieved for reads and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMEK only encrypts the data at physical level (instance disk) the encryption and decryption on the SQL queries is totally handled by the Cloud SQL instance at OS level, for this reason it is not necessary to add more information to the connection string in order to retrieve information.

As is mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-cmek), only in this scenarios it is necessary to share the CMEK key

- Creating a backup
- Creating a replica
- Creating a clone

This is because these operations need access to the disk data and this data is encrypted by the CMEK key.

If you are interested in encrypt the communication between the instance and other services you can use SSL/TLS certificates as is mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I understand data is encrypted when stored, I assume then during data retrieval it’s decrypted using the same CMEK under the hood?